# How to position modal box on exact position when's loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i have tried to find how to do this but unfortunately I haven't find anything similar. So I need to dynamically calculate the position of each image loaded in twitter modal box and position the box underneath the toolbar element which I've made. Situation is like in the image. Height of toolbar box is 40px and this should be done with javascript not with position fixed or what so ever.

[image]

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ax98jm2w/)

**Js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // - jQuery
    // Swipe feature
    $('#myCarousel').swiperight(function () {
      $('#myCarousel').carousel('prev');
    });
    $('#myCarousel').swipeleft(function () {
      $('#myCarousel').carousel('next');
    });

    // Carousel pause
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      pause: true,
      interval: false
    });

    // Additional toolbar with "close" button appears
    $(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      $('modal').modal('show');
      $('#toolbar').css('display', 'block'); //.css('position','fixed')
      console.log('fires toolbar');
    });

    $(window).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $('modal').modal('show');
      $('#toolbar').css('display', 'none'); //.css('position','absolute')
      console.log('closes toolbar when modal is closed');
    });

    // Closes modal on toolbar
    $('.trigger').click(function () {
      $('.modal').modal('hide');
    });

    // Load dynamic images
    $('.modal-trigger img').click(function (e) {
      $('#myModal img').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-img-url'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post your html/javascript here please? That link does not work properly.

Comment: Have you checked th "position" option of dialog ? http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position I think you can have something like `{my:"top-center", at:"bottom-center", of:"#my_toolbar"}`

Comment: Can you write a code sample for that pls? No I have not tried that yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making this far more complex than it needs to be.  If I understood correctly, you want to have a toolbar at the top of the image that spans the entire window when the modal is displayed and you want to have the image place directly below the toolbar with no additional spacing.  Assuming that is correct, you can do this with css to simply modify the existing look of the modal.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/ax98jm2w/9/)

**CSS**

```
.modal.fade.in {
    top: 0;
}
.modal {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.modal-header {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #b8b8b8);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: #a9a9a9;
    border-image: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 40px;
}
.modal-body {
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.modal-body img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
button.close {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 40px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active"> 
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="modal-trigger">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/e8117f/fff&text=Image%201" alt="" data-img-url="http://placehold.it/500/e8117f/fff&text=Image%201" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item"> 
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="modal-trigger">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/9ACD32/fff&text=Image%202" alt="" data-img-url="http://placehold.it/400/9ACD32/fff&text=Image%202" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item"> 
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="modal-trigger">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/FF6347/fff&text=Image%203" alt="" data-img-url="http://placehold.it/300/FF6347/fff&text=Image%203" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item"> 
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="modal-trigger">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/008080/fff&text=Image%204" alt="" data-img-url="http://placehold.it/500/008080/fff&text=Image%204" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>

<!-- Modal window -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="toolbar" class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" src="#" class="image" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. In your fiddle, you linked the bootstrap.min.js and then separately linked the files for the transitions and modal.  This is unnecessary.  The bootstrap.min.js file contains all of the javascript plugins in one file.

Comment: Thanks! Like you wrote i made it complex even if I didn't need to.. The problem I have solved with my css. While right now I am struggling to do the carousel effect when the modal box is opened. If you have some simple solution, I would be greatefull. Thanks!